# Use Hadoop from CDH in Ansible

Tags: ansible, cloudera-cdh

I want to use Hadoop from CDH docker image. CDH image is already installed on my machine and I can run it.

```
docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                        CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
07a55a9d4cb9        4239cd2958c6        "/usr/bin/docker-quickstart"   18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       0.0.0.0:32774->7180/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32773->8888/tcp   container


docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container

172.17.0.2
```

Local, I am writing an ansible playbook and I need to set Hadoop conf dir in CDH which is: "/etc/hadoop/conf". 
How can I set the running docker image in my ansible playbook?

I tried:

```
- name: run cloudera
  docker_container:
    name: "container"
    image: quickstart/cloudera
    command: /usr/bin/docker-quickstart"
    state: started
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
      - 7180:7180
```

But this command runs another docker image and I would like to connect to the running one.

Comment: try https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/docker.html rather than docker_container?

Comment: can you give me an example using these parameters?

Answer (score 1):

## inventory.ini

```
container ansible_connection=docker
```

*Note*: I suggest for the future that you rename your container to something more distinct than `container`....

## example playbook.yml

```yaml
---
- hosts: container

  tasks:
    - name: I am a dummy task, write your own
      file:
        path: /tmp/helloContainer
        state: file
```

## Running the playbook

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini playbook.yml
```